# Dynamic import is not working the same as regular import

Tags: javascript

I have this file in `../../src/routes/index.js`:

```
import Router from '../../my_modules/nexus/Router.js'

Router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.send('welcome home')
})

Router.get('/about', function (request, response) {
    response.send('about me')
})
```

I am trying to import this file via node because I want to create my own simple routing API class.

Here is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
import express from 'express'
import Router from './Router.js'

const app = express()

import '../../src/routes/index.js'
// import('../../src/routes/index.js')

console.log(Router.routes)

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`App listening on http://localhost:3000`)
})
```

This works:

```
import '../../src/routes/index.js'
// console.log(Router.routes) has the routes!
```

This does not work:

```
import('../../src/routes/index.js')
// console.log(Router.routes) is empty!
```

I need the 2nd example to work because I want to dynamically import a bunch of files from the `routes` directory. How do I get this to work using the `import()` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic import returns a `Promise` which you need to await (with `await` in an `async` function or by calling `then`) before running any code dependent on the imported module.

```
import express from 'express'
import Router from './Router.js'

const app = express()

import('../../src/routes/index.js').then(function () {
    console.log(Router.routes)

    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log(`App listening on http://localhost:3000`)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks actually just adding `await` before `import()` fixed it but you led me down the right path :)